# Extract all dates from dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe containing multiple date columns in each row. I want to extract all the dates to fill a new dataframe like a time dimension table:

```
date|day|month|year|dayofweek
```

Of course the new df should contain only unique datevalues.

Comment: Can u show us ur current dataframe sample as well?

Comment: Its like `ciid|name|desc|class|startdate|enddate|project|user|lastmoddate|decomdate.....`. So i want the dates from all those datecolumns. Dateformat is like 2016-07-24.

Comment: No link provided??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790610/splitting-date-into-year-month-and-day-with-inconsistent-delimiters